# Twitter::Error::ServiceUnavailable (Over capacity)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

Using twitter gem in rails 3 i am fetching some profile information but getting error. `Twitter::Error::ServiceUnavailable (Over capacity)`

Does any one have any idea how i can fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're interested in fixing twitter's capacity problems, https://about.twitter.com/careers is the place to start.

Otherwise you just have to wait for them to fix it.

Comment: OMG. Better i Should wait :)

Answer (score 1):

Go here to check the status

```
https://dev.twitter.com/status
```

You will see there is a service interruption